# Simple React Component Navigation

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying add some very simple click navigation to my React components. **App** is a component that can render either **Component1** or **Component2**. **Component1** contains a link that when clicked should tell **App** to render **Component2**.

The problem is when the anchor is clicked, **Component2** is displayed briefly and then **Component1** is rendered again instead. For some unexplained reason, **App.render()** is getting called twice: once when **state.view** is changed and once again after **Component2.render()** has been called. It appears that this second time **App.render()** is called it has an old state so it's rendering **Component1** instead.

Can anyone explain why **App.render()** is being called a second time and why **Component1** is being rendered after **Component2** has already been rendered?

I know I can use react-router to help me here but it seems like overkill for what I'm doing - AND I want to understand why this doesn't work the way I expect it to.

jsbin: http://jsbin.com/dosodeg/18

*For some reason, Component1 doesn't re-render in jsbin's or Stackoverflow's in-app preview panes. Instead, Component2 is displayed briefly and then the page goes blank. Open the output in a separate window to see the actual behavior.*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>App</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Troubleshooting SPA Component Navigation in React">
  <meta name="author" content="Jeremy McLain">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser-polyfill.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
<script type="text/babel">
var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      view: <Component1 setView={this.setView} />
    };
  },
  setView: function(view) {
    switch(view) {
      case "component1":
        this.setState({view: <Component1 setView={this.setView} />});
        break;
      case "component2":
        this.setState({view: <Component2 setView={this.setView} />});
        break;
    }
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>App</h3>
        { this.state.view }
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Component1 = React.createClass({
  component2Click: function(event) {
    this.props.setView("component2");
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>Component1</h4>
        <p><a href="" onClick={this.component2Click}>Component2</a></p>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Component2 = React.createClass({
  component1Click: function(event) {
    this.props.setView("component1");
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>Component2</h4>
        <p><a href="" onClick={this.component1Click}>Component1</a></p>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />
  , document.getElementById("container"));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your links have an empty href. When you click them, it changes the current URL to the same value, which triggers a reload. You can remove the href attribute or use event.preventDefault() in the onClick handler.